# How to connect tradingview to 3commas (stop loss)

Tags: pine-script

How can I put the stop loss in my strategy in tradingview to 3commas bot?
I am using this code for trailing profit and stop loss

```
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, when = short)
strategy.exit("short exit","Short",trail_points=0.005*close/syminfo.mintick,trail_offset=0.002*close/syminfo.mintick,loss=0.015*close/syminfo.mintick)
```

I searched couples of time and didn't found any thing
and if there is way to put "Trailing stop loss " in this code and connect it with 3commas i will be greatfull !

Answer (score 0):

as 3commas has provided an individual signal for "trailing take profit", you could put this signal in the alert_message of your strategy.exit(). it will work fine for your 3commas bot, but you may not see the perfect result with trailing in the backtesting.